# could not get unknown property 'flutterSdkpath' for settings 'android' of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I have this flutter project which i purchased from codecanyon, now when i try to run this in android studio i get this error "could not get unknown property 'flutterSdkpath' for settings 'android' of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings", i already have flutter.sdk='C:\flutter'in local.properties file but somehow its still showing this error

the error is in setting.gradle file which has this code:

def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
def properties = new Properties()

assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader -> properties.load(reader) }

def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
apply from: "$flutterSdkpath\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\app_plugin_loader.gradle"

Also this is my code in local.properties:

sdk.dir=C:\Users\shubby\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
flutter.sdk='C:\flutter'

Can someone please help and tell me what am i missing? Thanks

P.S. my flutter version is 2.5.2-stable

Answer (score 0):

Add your flutter.sdk='C:\flutter' path into the Environment path and restart your pc or laptop. After you can open the android studio and open your codecanyon projects android folder and click Gradle sync after it's completed success full then click the build button then that it's run success full you can run your full flutter project.

Comment: i did it, but its still the same, please note pub get is not generating any error, it onnly shows this error when i build apk by going to Build>Flutter>Build APK

Comment: Yes, it's correct no issue pub get, the issue on inside the Gradle run so you can run Gradle sync properly @CP

Comment: yes i understand, but when i build apk, it shows this error "Could not get unknown property 'flutterSdkpath' for settings 'android' of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings." –

i have flutter added in environment path (i can run doctor and other commands from terminal without any problem which means that android studio can detect flutter sdk)

Comment: and there is one strange thing: in local.properties file, i edited flutter.sdk=C:\\flutter
 to flutter.sdk=C:\\Users\\shubby\\flutter (i was checking this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61371222/flutter-location-error-with-settings-gradle) but everytime i do this and close the file and open it again it again goes back to flutter.sdk=C:\\flutter

Answer (score 0):

go to `android => settings.gradle`
and then replace all in with

```
include ':app'

def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
def properties = new Properties()

assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader -> properties.load(reader) }

def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"
```